# How to make vscode's emmet allow expanding all custom tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Previously when typing something in vscode like :-

`asd[TAB]
dada[TAB]
sasa[TAB]`

would expand into

`<asd></asd>
<dada></dada>
<sasa></sasa>`

but currently with the implementation of Emmet 2.0 this has changed.
Now it allows expanding html related tags only like ul, li, div, span, etc.

Please tell me if there's a way to obtain the functionality that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have

> // When enabled, Emmet abbreviations are expanded when pressing TAB.

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false,
```

in your settings.  That is the default, change it to true and it works for me for whatever tags I create.

Comment: Thanks man, you are awesome, didn't knew that this was the setting & was searching for it for ages.